# VS2022 Cannot open compiler intermediate file

Tags: compiler-bug

I am working in a Native Unit Test C++ project in VS2022 and I am trying to run some unit tests implemented in the source folder in UnitTest1.cpp file. However, when I am building the project, I have this error:[VS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4ZIA.png)

The named file exists at the indicated path in my computer.

Initially, the error was about the pch.h file which was also not found by compiler, but using preferences settings, the compiler sees the file.

Now, the error is related to de debug folder.